# Connection Error for Accessing .mdf after setup

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, installshield, mdf

I am building a Desktop App with local .mdf database in VB.NET,I am successfully using the software after installing it from the installer in my main machine where I developed the software via Visual Studio(i.e, naturally SQL Server is installed on that machine).
But When I tried to run the same installer in other machine without Microsoft sql server installed -it was installed successfully-BUT it failed while trying to connect to the .mdf database- giving the message as-

[image]

What should I do ? Is it only the Microsoft SQL server not insstalled-which is causing problem?
IF THIS IS THE CASE HOW CAN I HANDLE THIS SITUATION WHERE i MAY FIND MY CLIENT MACHINE SQL SERVER NOT INSTALLED?i.e. Should I modify the pre-requisites?(But I don't have the pre-requisite option of MS SQL Server in Installshield LE).

Comment: If you want to use a SQL Server database then you need SQL Server installed.

Comment: yes,as A developer now i am understanding that gradually-but I cannot tell if the client have installed sql server(mentioned completely on the last para)

Comment: You might want to have a look at something like Advanced Installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, It was the sqlLocalDB which was needed as I was working with .mdf database files.I installed it from Microsoft site-the [SQL Server Express LocalDB addon](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/)